# Are all non-boss monsters tameable?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've noticed that if you check the Libra screen for monsters, it says their taming status (either 'tamed', 'tameable', or 'untameable').  I have yet to see a common enemy that isn't tameable so I haven't really been paying any mind to this.

I'm assuming that it's ONLY bosses and other storyline-related enemies that aren't tameable but I figured it's worth asking.  Is EVERY random encounter enemy in the game tameable?  If not, which aren't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that none of the bosses are tameable, however not all monsters are tameable.

Not sure whether you would consider the `Long Gui` a natural fight or a boss or whatever but he certainly isn't tameable and neither are the following:
 Any `Cie'th`:

- `Ghoul`
- `Ghast`
- `Strigoi`
- `Taxim`
- `Vampire`
- `Geiseric`
- `Fomoire`
- `Wladislaus`
- `Malebranche`
- `Nelapsi`
- `Varcolaci`
- `Chonchon`
- `Cocytus`
- `Ispusteke`
- `Seeker`
- `Zenobia`
- `Vaballathus`
- `Gorgyra`
- `Raspatil`

There is also a full comprehensible guide on tameable monsters found here:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/faqs/63731

Comment: I didn't think about Ci'eth, oversight on my part. >.<  Other than that, it does look like most everything that isn't 'special' is tameable but the exceptions are nice to know.  Thanks!

Comment: I tamed all the pulsework guys so I don't think this is correct.

Comment: Somebody's claiming the the Pulsework are tameable.  I'll have to check on my bestiary later...

Comment: Easiest way is to press (PS3) R1, and then you can see if it's tameable from the info in the bottom right.

Comment: I can provide proof, if necessary.

Comment: After having a look I see that `Pulsework` are in fact tameable. The source I was using in my answer is obviously wrong. Apologies

Comment: @danRhul - Thanks for the correction.  I've left this marked as the accepted answer, because even though you were wrong out of the gate this is a better answer for still including a full list of Cie'th - I know sometimes in fights it can be hard to see what I'm even fighting except for by name. :)

Answer (score 1):

All the monsters you will encounter randomly in battle are tameable. Monsters that are bosses and cie'th are not tameable

Comment: George, this is incorrect, as you can see from my answer, `Pulsework` monsters are also not tameable

Comment: Actually, the Pulsework monsters are tameable.  The strategy guide specifically recommends using the Pulsework Gladiator as infusion fodder for the silver chocobo, and I can confirm I have tamed it at least twice.

Comment: @fbueckert & George, my apologies

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But all Cie'th are untamable. Bosses aren't tamable too. But some monsters that seems strong are tamable, like behemoths and tomberrys.